# Convert string to HTML to inject to paragraph via WebMethod

Tags: c#, jquery, visual-studio-2010, webforms

Im doing a Maintenance Page where people can store the description of what it will say in a Resource file, at this point in the requirement they dont even know if the text will be pure text or will have tags like `<a></a>`. So at this point I have to assume it will be the case.

This proyect have been made in Webforms framework 3.5 in VS2010.

For simplicity sake I'll reveal the relevant parts:

```
<article>
    <img alt="an image" src="Images/logo.jpg"/>
    <h2>Site under Maintenance</h2>
    <div>
        <p id="Description"></p>
    </div>
</article>

<script src="Includes/jquery-1.12.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "MaintenanceSite.aspx/GetMaintenanceDescription",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                $("#Description").text(msg.d);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Backend:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public static string GetMaintenanceDescription()
{
    string mensaje = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Resources.MaintenanceDescription);
    return mensaje;
}
```

The problem is, Im receiving this on my paragraph:

```
&lt;To href=&quot;&quot;&gt;Contact Us&lt;/a&gt;
```

(without the spaces as stack overflow is parsing the html correctly).

What am I missing?

Comment: html() is writing " <a href="">Contact us</a> " instead of the html a tag

Comment: Thank you, working perfectly

Comment: Glad you got it working. I added an answer for you below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two issues here. Firstly you need to remove the call to `HtmlEncode()` in the C# logic to return a plain HTML string. Secondly you need to use jQuery's `html()` method to display it instead of `text()`, as the latter will again encode the HTML.

```csharp
string mensaje = Resources.MaintenanceDescription;
```

```js
$("#Description").html(msg.d);
```